# How to use Animation while managing state (GetX)?

Tags: flutter, animation, state-management, flutter-getx

I am struggling trying to figure out how to simultaneously implement animation while using a state management solution (GetX). With this code in the UI:

```
     class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      late AnimationController animController;
      late Animation topPlayerCard1;
      late Animation leftPlayerCard1;

     @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        animController = AnimationController(
            vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
        topPlayerCard1 = Tween<double>(begin: -1, end: 0.95).animate(
            CurvedAnimation(
                parent: animController,
                curve: Interval(0.0, 0.30, curve: Curves.decelerate)));
        leftPlayerCard1 = Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: -0.2).animate(
            CurvedAnimation(
                parent: animController,
                curve: Interval(0.0, 0.30, curve: Curves.decelerate)));
        animController.addListener(() {
          setState(() {});
        });
        animController.forward();
      }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DeckController deckController = DeckController(); //GetX Controller
    deckController.makeDeck();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment(
                leftPlayerCard1.value,
                topPlayerCard1.value,
              ),
              child: Obx(
                () => buildCard(deckController.playerCard1.value),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Next Cards'),
              onPressed: () {
                deckController.playerCard1.value = deckController.getNextCard();
                //Make the cards move
                animController.reset();
                animController.forward();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

the playing card image slides across the screen and will do so each time the button's clicked. However, because `setState` is called repeatedly (I think), the `cardsDealt` variable in the GetXController continually resets to 0 as the controller is continually reinitiated (so `getNextCard()` always returns the same value from the `deck` list):

```
   class DeckController extends GetxController {
  var deck = <PlayingCard>[].obs;
  var cardsDealt = 0;
  var playerCard1 = PlayingCard(suit: CardSuit.S, value: CardValue.ace).obs;
  var playerCard2 = PlayingCard(suit: CardSuit.S, value: CardValue.ace).obs;
  var dealerCard = PlayingCard(suit: CardSuit.S, value: CardValue.ace).obs;

  void makeDeck() {
    // make standard 52 card deck
    final _deck = RxList<PlayingCard>();
    CardSuit.values.forEach((suit) {
      CardValue.values.forEach((type) {
        _deck.add(PlayingCard(
          value: type,
          suit: suit,
        ));
      });
    });
    deck = _deck;
  }

  void shuffleNewDeck() {
    makeDeck();
    deck.shuffle();
    cardsDealt = 0;
  }

  PlayingCard getNextCard() {
    PlayingCard _card;
    if (cardsDealt <= 51) {
      _card = deck[cardsDealt];
      cardsDealt++;
    } else
      _card = deck[0];
    return _card;
  }
```

In addition, having the stateful UI seems opposite to what state management is supposed to be about. How do I write this code so that the card image slides across the screen AND the `PlayingCard` object returned by `getNextCard()` changes each time the UI button is tapped?

Comment: make `DeckController deckController` a field in your `State` class, not a local variable inside `build` method? i never used `getx` but this is the first thing i would start with

Comment: @pskink Yes, of course. I feel like an idiot :-) Your point is excellent.